# Product Form Modifier Datetime Can't store correct DateTime to product attributes

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, datetime, modifier

I created a product attribute  called datedate  want to store DateTime, in default Magento product attributes, just have a date input type, so I using Ui Modifier to config date picker support time, but it just shows ok:

[image]

if submit the data, attribute looks like this, it seems stored not correct

[image]

this is my modifier code:

```
namespace XXX\XXXX\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

/**
 * Data provider for "Custom Attribute" field of product page
 */
class Datetime extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @param ArrayManager                $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = $this->enableTime($meta);

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Customise Custom Attribute field
     *
     * @param array $meta
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function enableTime(array $meta)
    {
        $fieldCode = 'datedate';

        $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
        $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');


        if (!$elementPath) {
            return $meta;
        }

        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $containerPath,
            $meta,
            [
                'children'  => [
                    $fieldCode => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [

                                    'options'       => [
                                        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                                        'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm',
                                        "storeTimeZone"=>"Asia/Shanghai",
                                        'showsTime' => true,
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                ]
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding plugin

```
class AddTimeSelectorPlugin
{

    protected $arrayManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager $arrayManager
    )
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing $subject
     * @param $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing $subject,
        $meta
    ) {
        $meta = $this->addTimeSelector($meta);
        return $meta;
    }

    protected function addTimeSelector($meta)
    {
        $pathFrom = $this->arrayManager->findPath('special_from_date', $meta, null, 'children');
        $pathTo = $this->arrayManager->findPath('special_to_date', $meta, null, 'children');
        if ($pathFrom && $pathTo) {
            $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                $pathFrom . '/arguments/data/config',
                $meta,
                [
                    'outputDateTimeToISO' => false,
                    'inputDateTimeFormat' => 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm',
                    'options' => [
                        'showsTime' => true,
                    ]
                ]
            );

            $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                $pathTo . '/arguments/data/config',
                $meta,
                [
                    'outputDateTimeToISO' => false,
                    'inputDateTimeFormat' => 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm',
                    'options' => [
                        'showsTime' => true,
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }

        return $meta;
    }
}
```